# How do I write all the printed items in .txt file as an output in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have hundreds of print statements and some are inside the loop. Although all these print statements get displayed while running the code, I also want all the summarized output file written in realtime or at the completion of the job.

for example

```
     print("first print and write.txt")
     check<-1:50
     for(i in 1:length(check)){
     print(paste0("this is what I want to print and then write output",i))
     print(paste0("this is another I want to print and then write output.txt",i))
     }
```

Comment: Instead of `print()`, use `cat()`.  It has a `file` argument

Comment: @Richard Scriven answered in using "cat" but I would add the append=TRUE argument to append the resulting file.

Comment: The `futile.logger` pkg can do both print to console and to a file and is pretty configurable.

Comment: also function `capture.output` may be useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the `sink()` function.
You can find some information here

http://www.statmethods.net/interface/io.html

You can setup to which file you want to write, and then you can use `cat()` to output information. You can even have output sent to the file and to the console.